# Objective-C (Upload a Single Image to a Server)

Tags: ios, objective-c

All,

I just want to upload a single screenshot from my App to a server directory.  The screenshot code works good as I can send it via SMS in another routine and it compiles just fine, but I don't see the image in the server directory using the code below.

I just can't get it to work. I ONLY care to upload the screenshotimage variable...the rest of the data is not important to me.  Please Help!!!

```
- (IBAction)sendToServer {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenshotimage,0.2);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.nameofmywebsite.com/temp/image_from_payer_app"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     NSString *boundary = @"xxxxBoundaryStringxxxx";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"iphoneimage.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
   NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

Here is my new code.  I am only trying to send a single image file (which is a screenshot of the app) to a server.  Can someone please verify that the client code is correct then I can just focus on the server side to see why the file is not being deposited on the server?

```
- (IBAction)sendToServer {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenshotimage,0.2);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData];


   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

   NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
}
```

Comment: And you have no further information?  I don't think you are trying very hard.

Comment: Could you add some information about the server implementation, and possible logs (both client and server)?

Answer (score 1):

Your client side code is seems ok. There might be some problem at your server side. Your server might unable to retrieve the image.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I was unable to comment so i thought it might help. I should delete it.

Comment: Yes the rep-requirement for commenting is frustrating.

Comment: I have updated my code.  My problem is that I'm trying to send a single image file to a server.

Comment: Both methods will send image file to the server. But Afnetworking 2.0 makes it super easy.

Comment: Although your old code is also good to be processed on server side.